# Size of List changes when converted to Set

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, set

I have an ArrayList:

```
List<MyClass> xxx = new ArrayList<MyClass>(functionThatGetsAList());
```

When I test `xxx.size()` I get 3, which is right. Then I try to cast:

```
Set<MyClass> yyy = new HashSet<MyClass>(xxx);
```

or alternatively:

```
Set<MyClass> yyy = new HashSet<MyClass>();
yyy.addAll(xxx);
```

In both cases `yyy.size()` is 1 and it only copies the first object. Why?

Comment: Show your actual code, what is in the array list? Set's remove duplicate entries. So if you had a list {1,1,1}, the set would be {1}.

Comment: Looks like the instances of `MyClass` in your `List<MyClass> xxx` have the same hash code and are the same by the definition of its `equals` method.

Comment: I've got ten pounds that says you need to implement `equals()` on `MyClass`

Comment: If you implement equals, also implement hashCode.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

> boolean   add(E e)
>   Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.

Try adding those elements from the list to the set in a loop.

does set.add(l); return true for every iteration? If not I think its safe to assume that the things that you are trying to add to the set are the same thing as determined by hashcode. If this is the case, you'll need to override hashcode().

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` relies on the `hashCode()` method in `Object`.  If you need a hash code, you need to override this method.  When overriding `hashCode()`, one must also override `equals()`.  See [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)